Mysterious TypeScript warning about Zod parser utility function
I am somewhat new to TypeScript and Zod, and I've figured out a lot on my own, but this example finally has me stumped. The code runs fine when I test it, but I'm getting a TypeScript warning about this line:
errors[fieldName] = fieldError._errors.join(' • ')

The warning is that the property _errors does not exist on the fieldError object, but it clearly looks like it does exist and is an array as expected, based on logging the value of fieldError immediately before that line and even logging typeof evaluations. I'm probably doing something wrong, but I have no idea what or how to even do a fuzzy search for related answers.
I'm trying to write a general utility function for using Zod to parse user-submitted data. Just pass it the Zod schema, the data to parse and get a result of success (with the parsed data) or failure (with an object of error messages by form field type, or just under the field name "form" if they are generalized errors).
My test of the function produces outputs as expected, so why is TypeScript warning me about type safety here? I think this is the minimum reproducible example of how I keep stumbling on that warning:
import type { ZodSchema } from 'zod'
import { z } from 'zod'

const testSchema = z.object({
  age: z.number(),
  username: z.string().min(1).max(24),
  imageUrl: z.string().url(),
})

const testData = {
  age: '93',
  username: 'SomeAbsurdlyLongUsername4u',
  imageUrl: 'httLCJyaWQiOiJ1c[malformedUrl]',
}

export default function zodParse({
  schema = testSchema,
  data = testData,
}: {
  schema: ZodSchema
  data: any
}) {
  const parseResult = schema.safeParse(data)
  if (parseResult.success) {
    const { data } = parseResult
    return { success: { data } }
  }
  const parseFailure = parseResult.error.format()
  const errors: { [key: string]: string } = {}
  for (const [fieldName, fieldError] of Object.entries(parseFailure)) {
    if (fieldName === '_errors') {
      if (fieldError.length) errors.form = fieldError.join(' • ')
    } else {
      errors[fieldName] = fieldError._errors.join(' • ')
    }
  }
  return { failure: { errors } }
}

I tried debugging the code by logging variable values to the console at every step, but those logs indicated that the property I was trying to access did exist and had the expected data type.

Try changing Object.entries(parseFailure) to Object.entries<ZodFormattedError>(parseFailure)

@Carcigenicate Trying that caused a different TS warning because ZodFormattedError uses a generic type. Without specifying it, type safety is ignored, same as Object.entries<any>(). I tried using a type made with z.inferFormattedError<typeof schema> for the generic, but it is a mismatch.
Your comment was still helpful, as the recursiveZodFormattedError type indicated a flaw in my code: it doesn't handle nested objects in the schema. Now I use .flatten() in place of .format() when the schema is flat, and a recursive function when there are nested objects.
